# Google Map + Navigation Drawer = No Marker? in Android Studio

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation-drawer, marker

I am a newbie in Android Development.

I made a Google Map activity from android studio wizard,I´ve also made a navigation drawer activity using the same wizard and they work great.

I´ve combined them by creating a Navigation drawer and inserting the Google Map fragment in it, and its quite good, aside from this issues:

1. The marker is not showing.
2. The current location marker is not showing.

Oh, sorry for the late reply, here is my sample code

After I created a navigation drawer, I create a Google maps activity, then from the "activity_maps.xml", I copy the whole  fragment (am I doing it right?)

Then I paste it inside "fragment_main,xml".. like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"     android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label"     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />



<!--THIS IS THE GOOGLE MAP FRAGMENT FROM activity_maps.xml-->
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context="com.e_mergetechnologies.embereye.MapsActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
<!--///////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

^_^Thanks guys in advanced!

Comment: You should add some of your code, this way other 'SOers' could identify the issue faster.

Comment: Take look at [this](https://github.com/jbj88817/MapTab-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/bojie/materialtest/fragments/UpcomingFragment.java#L69-L77) source code, you will know how to let the marker and current location dot show.